# How to restore the MBR partition table of MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, dual-boot, efi

I am using a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.2. While trying to triple boot my mac, I updated my MBR partition tables using rEFIt. Things didn't go as planned and now I want to start afresh. How can I reset my MBR partition table. I can handle partitioning disk on my own.

Comment: What did you try yet? Disk Utility?

Comment: I'm afraid the last time I tried disk utility I lost the ability to boot into Mac. Can't do that now.